# c# - Index out of range in the SubItems index for Listview

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2013, indexoutofrangeexception

I have this code where I want to add text at a certain column while all the other columns are left the way they are. However, when I increase the index of SubItems from 0 to 1 or 2, it gives me an error that says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.

This is my code:

```
if (flag == false)
{
    string period = txt_gradingPeriod.Text;
    string numeric = txt_numValue.Text;
    int cell = 0;
    
    if (period == "1st") { cell = 1; }
    else if (period == "2nd") { cell = 2; }
    else if (period == "3rd") { cell = 3; }
    else if (period == "4th") { cell = 4; }
    
    foreach (ColumnHeader header in listView1.Columns)
    {
        if (header.Text == period)
        {
            listView1.Items[0].SubItems[cell].Text = numeric;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess your ListViewer hasn't been assigned all the items. 
Where are you populating the ListViewer, does it have more than 1 item? If not then this would throw the error you are seeing.

Posted as answer as I can't comment.